# Middleware is not properly handling 403, but is properly handling 404

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I am trying to build in some custom handling of different error codes, and yet I seem to be having difficulties for my 403 codes. The code is identical between the 404 and 403s, and yet the 404 works correctly, and the 403 does not.

Here is my code:

```
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            await next();
            if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404)
            {
                context.Request.Path = "/Home/Error404";
                await next.Invoke();
            }
            else if(context.Response.StatusCode == 401)
            {
                string referer = context.Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString();
                if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(referer))
                {
                    referer = context.Request.Path;
                }
                context.Response.Redirect($"/Home/Login?returnUrl={referer}");
            }
            else if (context.Response.StatusCode == 403)
            {
                context.Request.Path = "/Home/Error403";
                await next.Invoke();

                //context.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error403");
            }
        });
```

I've verified with breakpoints that the 403 code is triggering, and the code in my home controller is quite simple:

```
    [Route("/Home/Error403")]
    public IActionResult Error403()
    {
        return View("~/Views/Shared/Error403.cshtml");
    }

    [Route("/Home/Error404")]
    public IActionResult Error404()
    {
        return View("~/Views/Shared/Error404.cshtml");
    }
```

For some reason Error404 gets called but not Error403. My 401 code redirects correctly as well. I just have no idea why it's not working here. I did try a redirect for the 403, and that worked, but it's less than ideal.

Comment: what does "not work" mean in your context. What happens with your original code on error 403?

Comment: By not work I mean the function Error403() is never called. Error404() is however (on 404 errors)

Answer (score 0):

Where in your OWIN pipeline is this middleware happening?

If you declare this handler before you declare your Authentication handlers, then you will never have a 403 to handle.

Define this handler after you have declared and configured the Authentication middleware, and it can respond to the 403 status that it will set.